# Скрытые файлы или папки found

Tags: wordpress

При разработке темы Wordpress во время проверки theme chek выскакивает ошибка  ВНИМАНИЕ!: .bin .travis.yml Скрытые файлы или папки found.
Кто нибудь знаком с подобным, что это может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При разработке в папке темы или плагина обычно находится много скрытых файлов, например, `*.yml`, '.gitignore'. Они нужны на этапе разработки для поддержания определённых инструментов - Git, Travis и прочих. В "production" - конечном варианте для пользователя они не нужны, и их обычно удаляют из публикуемой версии.

Если вы собираетесь публиковать где-то вашу тему, стоит эти файлы удалить в варианте для публикации.